# duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 while using NMAKit SDK

Tags: ios, here-api

I am trying out HERE_IOS_SDK_v3.0.2, after adding the framework and the bundle, I keep getting this compiling error. In target build settings -> other links flag I already have -objc, lc++ and load_all there. Did I miss something?

errors when compiling:

[image: errors when compiling]

Comment: "Do the same for the NMABundle.bundle file. This file is found in the HelloMap/NMAKit.framework/Resource directory. However, do not select the "Copy items if needed" option."
In the here-dk integration docs.Double check it

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan thanks for the answer. Sorry man I followed the steps in the doc. But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try removing load_all flag from your Xcode setting ?  Also double check your linkage to NMAKit and make sure it is not linked twice (pointing to multiple different NMAKit files).  The symbol duplication seems to be all coming from inside the SDK itself so it is likely caused by some compiler / linker flag issue...